# Theme.json Wordpress - Bold Font Weight of Google Font Doesn't Show in Chrome, only in Safari

Tags: json, wordpress, themes, block

I'm building my own WordPress Block Theme and have the following issue.

I'm trying to enrol the Google Font "PT Serif" via my theme.json. It works like a charm with Chrome and Safari, however, just for the regular 400 font-weight.

The bold 700 font-weight is reflected in Safari, but not in Chrome. Has anyone a solution for me? I've been sitting on this for hours.

Here's the full theme.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "appearanceTools": true,
        "color": {
            "palette": [
                {
                    "slug": "background",
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "name": "Background"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "foreground",
                    "color": "#2e2e2e",
                    "name": "Foreground"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "primary",
                    "color": "#1c569e",
                    "name": "Primary"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "secondary",
                    "color": "#ffc860",
                    "name": "Secondary"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "consulterce-blue",
                    "color": "#15212a",
                    "name": "Consulterce Blue"
                }
            ]
        },
        "layout": {
            "contentSize": "700px",
            "wideSize": "1100px"
        },
        "spacing": {
            "units": [ "px", "em", "rem", "vh", "vw", "%" ]
        },
        "typography": {
            "fontFamilies": [
              {
                "fontFamily": "\"PT Serif\", serif",
                "name": "PT Serif",
                "slug": "pt-serif",
                "fontFace": [
                  {
                    "fontFamily": "PT Serif",
                    "fontWeight": "400",
                    "fontStyle": "normal",
                    "fontStretch": "normal",
                    "src": [ "file:./fonts/pt-serif-v17-latin-regular.woff2" ]
                  },
                  {
                    "fontFamily": "PT Serif",
                    "fontWeight": "700",
                    "fontStyle": "bold",
                    "fontStretch": "normal",
                    "src": [ "file:./fonts/pt-serif-v17-latin-700.woff2" ]
                  },
                  {
                    "fontFamily": "PT Serif",
                    "fontWeight": "400",
                    "fontStyle": "italic",
                    "fontStretch": "normal",
                    "src": [ "file:./fonts/pt-serif-v17-latin-italic.woff2" ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
        }
    },
    "styles": {
        "typography": {
            "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--pt-serif)"
        },
        "color": {
            "background": "var(--wp--preset--color--background)",
            "text": "var(--wp--preset--color--foreground)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your safari version? and did you test the issue with `.ttf` src as well?

Comment: Chrome Version: Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (arm64)
Safari Version: Version 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12)

And yes, I tested it with .ttf as well - same behaviour. The thing is, Chrome uses PT Serif Regular correctly, so it seems to be an issue with the way it calls the bold and italic versions. File locations have been verified, so it's not related to an incorrect file location.